# MAC: Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules.asar.unpacked/@vscode/ripgrep/bin/rg EMFILE

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code

Searching is not working in VS code.

Error:

```
spawn /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules.asar.unpacked/@vscode/ripgrep/bin/rg EMFILE**
  log.ts:404   ERR [Extension Host] Error: spawn /Applications/Visual Studio           Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/node_modules.asar.unpacked/@vscode/ripgrep/bin/rg EMFILE
   at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:283:19)
  at onErrorNT (node:internal/child_process:478:16)
  at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

[image]
[image]

**VS code details:**

```
Version: 1.75.1 (Universal)
Commit: 441438abd1ac652551dbe4d408dfcec8a499b8bf
Date: 2023-02-08T21:34:59.000Z (1 wk ago)
Electron: 19.1.9
Chromium: 102.0.5005.194
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.23-electron.0
OS: Darwin x64 22.3.0
Sandboxed: No
```

Read the link given below for this error however does not able to understand to proceed.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/9872